# Write a custom HtmlResponseWriter JSF

Tags: java, jsf, components, render

For many internal problems that doesn't count now, We have a Servlet filter that changes all outcome that's `application/xhtml+xml` and rewrite to `text/html;charset=UTF-8` so even using the facelets it'll work with no problem with IE 6.0.

My question is on the HtmlResponseWriter, which is the component responsible for the rendering. Is it possible to extend it and override its methods so we accomplish the desired effect of the filter?

- The content type will always be output as text/html;
- The encoding will be always `UTF-8;`
- The script tag will be wrapped inside a `< ! -- <[[CDATA ]]> -->` .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where exactly does `application/xhtml+xml` come from? Standard JSF/Facelets doesn't emit that by default. Why don't you just fix it right there instead of overriding the renderer?

Comment: Hello BalusC, the template contains <f:view contentType="application/xhtml+xml">, to include the cdata in the javascript, but fooling the browser (IE-6 actually) to read the response as text/html.

so the all the requests that produces text/html responses are served as application/xhtml+xml but the filter set it to text/html. I'll look for more info to better answer your considerations.

Comment: I'd just serve as `text/html` and move the JS into its own `.js` file which you load by `<script src="file.js">`. Btw: using `@nickname` like `@BalusC` in comments will automatically notify specific users about specific comments. I didn't see your comment until I browsed this topic back :)

Comment: ohhh @BalusC sorry :/, so I chat with some of the man behind the filter and he explained to me that we must serve inline js with CDATA and some tags as we were with "app/xhtml+xml" so that's the why the template is set to this content type and the filter alter it to text/html. So my question persists, is it valid and possible to overite the HtmlResponseWriter?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't make sense to use `application/xhtml+xml` anyway. You could just set it to `text/html`. It'll work as good and you don't need to override the writer.

Comment: but wont pass w3c validator as xhtml

Comment: Then use HTML5 doctype: `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Comment: Can't :/ is against the rules of the comp. all messed up :( but again, I know you're clearly right about the proper usage of it. But I need to have that messy behavior that I've described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we have extended JSF (actually Oracle ADF) components in order to meet special requirements that could not be done out of the box. You will need to get all of the source files of those renders and do a recursive search for the offending HTML you want removed, the `application/xhtml+xml`. This is just to make sure it is in fact inside the `HtmlResponseWriter` class. JSF component frameworks can be complex so you never know, there may be other instances where this header is rendered.

Since the `HtmlResponseWriter` isn't declared `final` like some components are, you can just extend this, and override the method where `application/xhtml+xml` is being printed and [register it](http://www.coderanch.com/t/213094/JSF/java/Extending-JSF-Components) in `faces-config.xml`. The only obstacles to this is if there are private variables declared inside of `HtmlResponseWriter` being referenced in the method that you need to override. If that is the case you will either not be able to reference them in your reimplementation or you will have to completely re-build a new `HtmlResponseWriter` class (by extending the `ResponseWriter` and mimicking each method and instance variable). The benefit of extending the `HTMLResponseWriter` is that you will pick up any changes (from JSF updates) to it automatically (except in the overridden method of course).

Update:
This is what I did for my faces-config.xml, but it is using Oracle ADF:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<faces-config version="1.2" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
  <application>
    <default-render-kit-id>oracle.adf.rich</default-render-kit-id>
  </application>
  <render-kit>
    <render-kit-id>oracle.adf.rich</render-kit-id>
    <renderer>
      <component-family>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.Input</component-family>
      <renderer-type>oracle.adf.rich.Text</renderer-type>
      <renderer-class>com.company.jsf.renders.text.CustomRenderer</renderer-class>
    </renderer>
  </render-kit>
</faces-config>
```

Comment: yes! That is exactly what a need to do it but I don't know how to declare the extended component for proper usage. Could you provide me a little more info?

Comment: @Kamia, Once you have your Java Class written, point to it in faces-config.xml so that it registers the `HtmlResponseWriter` with your new class. I can provide an example, but this is from ADF though...

Comment: just found the steps needed to it, in the case of the ResponseWriter, isn't enough to use it.. you must rewrite the whole render kit or make a decorator to use with it to prevent the rewriting of all classes.

Ill close this question and give you the points since your answer led me to the book Pro JSF and Ajax (pg 237 to 264).

I Wish I could point @BalusC for that too.